# Firebase security - updating Firestore ddbb

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've got 2 collections: `Users` and `Recipes` (1:N)

`Recipes` have `likes` which haves `users.uid`: `likes: ['id1', 'id2' ... ]`

Knowing this, how can I push just my id and avoid pushing other user ids?

Comment: What do you mean by "push"?  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to allow or disallow?

Comment: add content to the array like `likes.push('userId')`

Comment: I want to avoid is exactly that, push other users id -->  `likes.push('userId1', 'userId2', 'userId3')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items to an array in Firestore, you have to read the document, set the contents of the array to whatever you want, then write the entire array back to the document.  There is no push operation on an array field.

Comment: I shouldn't be able to write the entire array, otherwise I could modify other people likes

Comment: Then you'll need to model your data differently.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

Comment: Interesting... so I'd have to change all my arrays to objects? Probably this is only for arrays that you want to use as filters right? In mi case I don't need to filter by `likes` just check with an `indexOf()` if I've got that `userId` on that recipe

Comment: If you want to filter with those array values, yes, you will have to use objects instead.

Comment: No, I don't want to filter by likes. I can use that logic when I need to filter by favs, but that's another property. Filter is only an array containing users ids

Comment: Any ideas mate?